# How to replace one NSString with specific NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my app, users have the ability to search for other users by entering an `@` and then some letters, at which point a popup will show with the potential usernames. I am stuck at the point where the user will select a username from the popup, which should replace the partially entered text with the selected username. For example, if I type:

**hi @jo**

and then select **john** from the table, then it should look like below

**hi @john**

But this is not happening. I have find one method called 
`stringByPaddingToLength`, but it work for only one character of the replaced text. If I search with two characters, it gives the wrong output. My code is following:

```
-(void)storeData:(NSString *)strName
{
    NSString *strText = textView.text;//the String which is enter in textview
    NSRange startRange = [strText rangeOfString:@"@"   options:NSBackwardsSearch];//find the range of '@' from currently pointed at backward
    strText = [strText stringByPaddingToLength:(strName.length + strText.length - 1)  withString:strName startingAtIndex:(startRange.location+startRange.length)];//the string after append the string
 }
```

If I enter **@ch** and then select "Chandru" it gives the following output:

> 2015-05-05 19:55:02.789 [3733:131086] StrName::@chhandru

If I just enter **@c** and then select "Chandru" it gives the following (correct) output.

> 2015-05-05 19:55:58.371 [3733:131086] StrName::@chandru

How can I make it display the correct username, no matter how many characters were already entered?

Comment: Why don't you entirely replace the old string by the new string instead of concatenating two pieces of strings ?

Comment: for example i have string like **@abc** but i if user replace **a** with **x** and any name come then it looks like **@xyz** bc now how can i replace entire string

Comment: So the aim is to allow the user to type @... and then to replace the dots with a selected name. And there will only be 1 @ in the text? And you should replace all the dots no matter where the edit was before the name was selected?

Comment: Yes I do excat same thing. This is done in Instagram

Comment: Why down votting? Is this question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: method on NSMutableString for this.

```
[strText replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@jo" withString:@"@john" options: CaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, strText.length)] ;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but how I able to find the string because it is in middle of the string also

Comment: for example i have string like **@abc** but i if user replace a with x and any name come then it looks like **@xyz bc** now how can i replace entire string

Comment: You replace xbc with xyzbc